# T-SQL XML nodes are interleaved

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql

I need the following XML structure

```
<root>
    <lkz>12345</lkz>
    <styles>
        <style>
            <productNo>
            ..
            </productNo>
        </style>
        <style>
            <productNo>
            ..
            </productNo>
        </style>
    </styles>
</root>
```

The table that I use

```
lkz   | productNo
------+----------------
12345 | 123456-789
12345 | 1213456-788
```

`lkz` is always the same

My T-SQL code:

```
DECLARE @xmlData XML

SET @xmlData = (SELECT productNo
                FROM dbo.otto
                FOR XML PATH ( 'Style' ), ROOT ('Styles'), ELEMENTS)

SELECT @xmlData
```

Result

```
<Styles>
  <Style>
    <productNo>123456-789</productNo>
  </Style>
  <Style>
    <productNo>123456-788</productNo>
  </Style>
</Styles>
```

Questions (sorry for my English):

1. How can I get  about "everything"
2. How can I get `<lkz>` only second line as simple node

THANKS for help !

Answer (score 2):

Do group by on `lkz` in the main query and get the corresponding `productNo` values in a sub-query.

```
select O1.lkz,
       (
       select O2.productNo
       from dbo.Otto as O2
       where O1.lkz = O2.lkz
       for xml path('style'), root('styles'), type
       )
from dbo.otto as O1
group by O1.lkz
for xml path(''), root('root');
```

Comment: can I integrate another XML Explicit?

SELECT
                                1 as Tag,  
                                0 as Parent,
                                'DE' as [ClusterAttribute1!1!CountryIsoCode],
                                ClusterAttribute1 as [ClusterAttribute1!1!!CDATA]
                    FROM
                    dbo.otto 
                    FOR XML EXPLICIT

Comment: Why do you want to use explicit?

Comment: for using cdata i must use XML Explicit !?!

my table has another colum:

ClusterAttribute1

an i need the result with cdate

sql only:

SELECT
        1 as Tag,  
        0 as Parent,
        'DE' as [ClusterAttribute1!1!CountryIsoCode],
        ClusterAttribute1 as [ClusterAttribute1!1!!CDATA]
     FROM
     dbo.otto as O3
     FOR XML EXPLICIT

result:

<ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE"><![CDATA[Herren]]></ClusterAttribute1>
<ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE"><![CDATA[Damen]]></ClusterAttribute1>

Comment: Yes, that is true. But do you really need cdata? If you add the result back to a xml variable or column it will be removed.

Comment: okay..

i can 

  <lkz>12345</lkz>
  <styles>
    <style>
      <stylesNo>123456-789</stylesNo>
      <ClassOfGoods>test1</ClassOfGoods>
      <ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE">Herren</ClusterAttribute1>
      <ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE">Damen</ClusterAttribute1>
    </style>
    <style>
      <stylesNo>123456-788</stylesNo>
      <ClassOfGoods>test2</ClassOfGoods>
      <ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE">Herren</ClusterAttribute1>
      <ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE">Damen</ClusterAttribute1>
    </style>
  </styles>

in output ?

Comment: You should update your question with some sample data and the expected result xml you are looking for using that data.

Answer (score 0):

my table

```
lkz|stylesNo|ClassOfGoods|ClusterAttribute1
12345|123456-789|test1|Herren
12345|123456-788|test2|Damen
```

to need xml

```
<root>
<LKZ>12345</LKZ>
<Styles>
<Style>
<StyleNo>123456-789</StyleNo>
<ClassOfGoods>test1</ClassOfGoods>
<ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE"><![CDATA[Herren]]></ClusterAttribute1>
```

my t-sql

```
SET @xmlData =
    (select O1.lkz,
                (
                select O2.stylesNo
                ,O2.ClassOfGoods

                ,(SELECT
                                1 as Tag,  
                                0 as Parent,
                                'DE' as [ClusterAttribute1!1!CountryIsoCode],
                                ClusterAttribute1 as [ClusterAttribute1!1!!CDATA]
                    FROM
                    dbo.otto as O3
                    --where O1.stylesNo = O3.stylesNo
                    FOR XML EXPLICIT, type
                    )

                from dbo.otto as O2 
                where O1.lkz = O2.lkz
                for xml path('style'), root('styles'), type
                )
    from dbo.otto as O1
    group by O1.lkz
    for xml path(''), root('ottopartner')
    )

SELECT @xmlData
```

result

```
<root>
  <lkz>12345</lkz>
  <styles>
    <style>
      <stylesNo>123456-789</stylesNo>
      <ClassOfGoods>test1</ClassOfGoods>
      <ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE">Herren</ClusterAttribute1>
      <ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE">Damen</ClusterAttribute1>
    </style>
    <style>
      <stylesNo>123456-788</stylesNo>
      <ClassOfGoods>test2</ClassOfGoods>
      <ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE">Herren</ClusterAttribute1>
      <ClusterAttribute1 CountryIsoCode="DE">Damen</ClusterAttribute1>
    </style>
  </styles>
</root>
```